# Tell if a HTTP client is disconnected

Tags: php, apache, http

I have a php/apache page that takes a long time to load. Basically, it looks like this:

```
<?php
      doHeavyStuff_1();
      doHeavyStuff_2();
      doHeavyStuff_3();
      printResults();
?>
```

It happens from time to time that the client disconnects in the middle of the processing, say, between step1 and step2. Is there a way in php to check if the client is still connected and to stop further processing if it isn't? I'd like my code to be like this:

```
<?php
      doHeavyStuff_1();
      if(<clientDisconnected>) die;
      doHeavyStuff_2();
      if(<clientDisconnected>) die;
      doHeavyStuff_3();
      if(<clientDisconnected>) die;
      printResults();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Look into using the [connection_aborted](http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

Normally PHP (as an apache module) should stop automatically if the user disconnects. No work is necessary.

Just if you are interested: if you want PHP to continue processing there is the function [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php). You should start to read the manual page and especially the comments to see how it can be used and which problems can occur.

Comment: He wants to stop further processing if the client disconnects. ignore_user_abort will do the opposite.

Comment: @WayneWhitty Oh, I didn't saw that. In that situation nothing should being necesarry. PHP will automatically termninate.